# Tensorflow: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to build a custom object detection model using the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md). Specifically, I want to add a distance estimation to each detected object. So, I extended the `SSDMetaArch` class and adapted/added some crucial parts. Among other things:

- added distance to the input
- adapted protos to handle distance
- created a new prediction head for distance estimations
- created new loss taking distances into account
- adapted postprocessing step to output distances

After all these steps the training seems to work and the losses (including the distance loss) go down.

But when I want to evaluate the model I get a

> RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.

Specifically the following line in the (adapted) `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` method in `visualization_utils.py` (around line 700) causes the error

```
          #the follwing line throws the error
          display_str = '{}: {}% -> {}'.format(display_str, int(100 * scores[i]), int(distances[i]))

          #No error is thrown using the original code
          #display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(display_str, int(100 * scores[i]))
```

It seems that just by printing the value the above exception is thrown.

**My Question:** I do not understand why printing a value will modify the graph. Could you help me understand why this is the case and if possible give me hint how I can avoid this modification to the graph.

Find the complete error below

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from E:/Data/OD_DE/tensorflow/models/model\model.ckpt-5103
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
2019-04-01 13:14:30.795741: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1261]  
Unknown: RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 206, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 271, in _visualize_boxes
    image, boxes, classes, scores, category_index=category_index, **kwargs)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 730, in visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
    print("We were definitely here:" + str(int(distances[i])))

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 525, in _slice_helper
    name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6037, in __exit__
    self._name_scope.__exit__(type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)

  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4016, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 500, in _slice_helper
    packed_begin, packed_end, packed_strides = (stack(begin), stack(end),

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 863, in stack
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1050, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    name=name).outputs[0]

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3246, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2919, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 206, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 271, in _visualize_boxes
    image, boxes, classes, scores, category_index=category_index, **kwargs)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 730, in visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
    print("We were definitely here:" + str(int(distances[i])))

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 525, in _slice_helper
    name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6037, in __exit__
    self._name_scope.__exit__(type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)

  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4016, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 500, in _slice_helper
    packed_begin, packed_end, packed_strides = (stack(begin), stack(end),

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 863, in stack
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1050, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    name=name).outputs[0]

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3246, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2919, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.


     [[{{node map_1/while/PyFunc}} = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_UINT8], _class=["loc:@map_1/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3"], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](map_1/while/Squeeze/_2907, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_3/_2909, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_4/_2911, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_5/_2913)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1023, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/JD/tensorflowod/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 110, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/JD/tensorflowod/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 105, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 610, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 711, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1241, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1471, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 671, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1156, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1255, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "c:\users\JD\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1240, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1320, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 582, in after_run
    if self._save(run_context.session, global_step):
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 607, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 517, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 537, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 912, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 478, in evaluate
    return _evaluate()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 467, in _evaluate
    output_dir=self.eval_dir(name))
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1591, in _evaluate_run
    config=self._session_config)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\evaluation.py", line 274, in _evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 671, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1156, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1255, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "c:\users\JD\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1240, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1312, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1076, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 206, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 271, in _visualize_boxes
    image, boxes, classes, scores, category_index=category_index, **kwargs)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 730, in visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
    print("We were definitely here:" + str(int(distances[i])))

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 525, in _slice_helper
    name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6037, in __exit__
    self._name_scope.__exit__(type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)

  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4016, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 500, in _slice_helper
    packed_begin, packed_end, packed_strides = (stack(begin), stack(end),

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 863, in stack
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1050, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    name=name).outputs[0]

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3246, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2919, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.


     [[node map_1/while/PyFunc (defined at ..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py:439)  = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_UINT8], _class=["loc:@map_1/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3"], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](map_1/while/Squeeze/_2907, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_3/_2909, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_4/_2911, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_5/_2913)]]

Caused by op 'map_1/while/PyFunc', defined at:
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1023, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/JD/tensorflowod/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 110, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/JD/tensorflowod/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py", line 105, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 610, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 711, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1241, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1471, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 671, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1156, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1240, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1320, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 582, in after_run
    if self._save(run_context.session, global_step):
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 607, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 517, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 537, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 912, in evaluate_and_export
    hooks=self._eval_spec.hooks)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 478, in evaluate
    return _evaluate()
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 460, in _evaluate
    self._evaluate_build_graph(input_fn, hooks, checkpoint_path))
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1484, in _evaluate_build_graph
    self._call_model_fn_eval(input_fn, self.config))
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1520, in _call_model_fn_eval
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.EVAL, config)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1195, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 443, in model_fn
    eval_dict)
  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 931, in get_estimator_eval_metric_ops
    images = self.images_from_evaluation_dict(eval_dict)
  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 995, in images_from_evaluation_dict
    self._min_score_thresh, self._use_normalized_coordinates)
  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 547, in draw_side_by_side_evaluation_image
    eval_dict[input_data_fields.groundtruth_distances][indx], axis=0) if input_data_fields.groundtruth_distances in eval_dict else None
  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 442, in draw_bounding_boxes_on_image_tensors
    images = tf.map_fn(draw_boxes, elems, dtype=tf.uint8, back_prop=False)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 494, in map_fn
    maximum_iterations=n)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3291, in while_loop
    return_same_structure)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3004, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2939, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3260, in <lambda>
    body = lambda i, lv: (i + 1, orig_body(*lv))
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 483, in compute
    packed_fn_values = fn(packed_values)
  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 439, in draw_boxes
    tf.uint8)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 457, in py_func
    func=func, inp=inp, Tout=Tout, stateful=stateful, eager=False, name=name)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 281, in _internal_py_func
    input=inp, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_script_ops.py", line 132, in py_func
    "PyFunc", input=input, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

UnknownError (see above for traceback): RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 206, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 271, in _visualize_boxes
    image, boxes, classes, scores, category_index=category_index, **kwargs)

  File "..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 730, in visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
    print("We were definitely here:" + str(int(distances[i])))

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 525, in _slice_helper
    name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6037, in __exit__
    self._name_scope.__exit__(type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)

  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4016, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 500, in _slice_helper
    packed_begin, packed_end, packed_strides = (stack(begin), stack(end),

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 863, in stack
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1050, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    name=name).outputs[0]

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3246, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()

  File "..\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2919, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.


     [[node map_1/while/PyFunc (defined at ..\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py:439)  = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_UINT8], _class=["loc:@map_1/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3"], token="pyfunc_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](map_1/while/Squeeze/_2907, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_3/_2909, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_4/_2911, map_1/while/TensorArrayReadV3_5/_2913)]]
```

Comment: While it is hard to tell from the question, I may propose a sanity checks. Can you check the type of 'distances' before printing? If you got them from a line like 'distances = session.run([distances_op])' than probably they should be a numpy array and not any sort of Tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in your case `distances` is a tensor and calling `distances[0]` attempts to create an array_slice operation on a finalized graph. The right way of handling that would be to feed `distances` tensor to your `distances_np = session.run(distances)` or call `distances_np = distances.eval()` providing necessary parameters to acquire some sort of numpy array and only then do indexing and/or printing on `distances_np`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I printed the types of scores and distances and got <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> respectively. Thanks a lot, I hope I can fix the problem now.